# Created pages/subpages in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning Django and I am trying to create a few pages and subpages on my site.

project

urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'home/', include('home.urls', namespace = 'home')),
    url(r'about/', include('about.views', namespace = 'About_page')),
)

I first create a home page:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from home import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render(request,'homepage_template/home.html')
```

Next I tried to create an about page but I get this error:

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
The included urlconf <module 'about.views' from '/home/bradford/Development/Django/pub_pic/about/views.pyc'> doesn't have any patterns in it
```

This is what my about app looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render(request,'About_template/about.html')
```

I don't have a urls.py but I thought the line

```
url(r'about/', include('about.views', namespace = 'About_page')),
```

would directly `include` the `about.views`. However I was wrong because this never called my `index()` function in `about/views.py`

I later changed the `url()` in `pub_pic/urls.py` to:

```
url(r'about/', include('about.views.index', namespace = 'About_page')),
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception Value:    
No module named index
```

I think this caused due to the fact that only `about.views` is a module, not `index()`

I'm not quite sure how to create pages or subpages and best practices for a well structured project. Could someone give me some suggestions please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project urls.py, you cannot include an application's view files in `urlpatterns`.

```
url(r'about/', include('about.urls', namespace = 'About_page')), )
```

And in about/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from about import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),)
```

If there is only one url in about/urls.py, then you can directly put it in urls.py of project.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'home/', include('home.urls', namespace = 'home')),
    url(r'^about/$', 'about.views.index', name="About_page_index"),
)
```